# How do I import a STL file to a geometrical set?

Tags: vba, catia

I want to automatically insert some STL objects to a geometrical set.

Without a macro I open “STL Rapid Prototyping” and use “STL import”.

I am trying to do several adjustments faster by automation and therefore I need to avoid this manual step. I tried to record this procedure but the result is useless for me.

**Is there a way to import an STL to a geometrical set with a (VBA) macro?**

(Usually, I work with Generative Shape Design and use VBA for Macros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but there are no APIs to perform the "Import STL" function on the STL workbench.

As far as I know the only way to automate this task are to use WINAPI methods; that is simulating window/mouse/keyboard interaction using window handles and Windows messages.  I have done exactly this task not too long ago. It is not difficult, it is just tedious.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). I don't know how to use WINAPI methods but I'll try it out if I have a little more time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to do it, but it fails sometimes:

1. Open the STL in a Assembly (Insert / Existing-component)
2. Switch to the DMU-Optimizer Workbench
3. Create an Zero-Offset to the part (Offest function with value 0)
4. Save the model as *.model (that is a CATIA V4 file-format)
5. Open the *.model file
6. Navigate the Tree and select&copy all faces
7. Open a NEW Catia(V5) Part and paste all faces

sometimes this works perfect, sometimes it crashes (on larger files) or it is missing some faces.